# Autodesk APS API and EU Region

Tags: autodesk-forge

When using https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/

DataManagement api's from autodesk why are my eu servers not in the response? (will this return back all hubs across both us and eu regions?)

It would be my understanding that this would return all my hubs across all regions?  At the current time, I only see my US hubs in the response.

Answer (score 0):

To access your EU account with the same client id, you must [provision](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/#provision-access-in-other-products) it in the custom integration of the EU account, as you did for the US account. Afterward, you should be able to see [GET Hubs](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/) returns hubs from US and EU servers like the below one.

```json
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs?filter%5Bextension.type%5D=hubs%3Aautodesk.bim360%3AAccount"
        }
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "hubs",
            "id": "b....",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "My Account 1",
                "extension": {
                    "type": "hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "schema": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account-1.0"
                    },
                    "data": {}
                },
                "region": "US" //!<<< US server
            },
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b...."
                }
            },
            "relationships": {
                "projects": {
                    "links": {
                        "related": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b..../projects"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "hubs",
            "id": "b....",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "My Account 2",
                "extension": {
                    "type": "hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "schema": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account-1.0"
                    },
                    "data": {}
                },
                "region": "EMEA" //!<<< EU server
            },
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b...."
                }
            },
            "relationships": {
                "projects": {
                    "links": {
                        "related": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b..../projects"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```